# Office- Word finding out the original created date of a file which was copied from another computer, is it possible?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

how can i find out the original created date of a word file, especially when the doc was copied from another comupter? (because then in the properties folder it shows the date when it was copied).

Answer (score 0):

You must archive a file before transfering it to keep its origional creation date, as it is the filesystem's responsibilty to keep track of this. As such rarely do files ever bother to store this inforamtion. So zip tar or rar it.